# C++ passing family of objects to class

Tags: c++, class, object, oop

I am trying to find a way to create a generic "car" class, with children that overload the parent's methods. Subsequently, I would like to have a user class that has as a member any class in the "car" family. Is there a way to achieve the desired functionality? Thank you!

The pseudocode below shows what my intial attempt was, but the compiler obviously complains that User wants a Car object, not a Toyota.

```
class Car
{
    public:
        Car();
        void method1();    
};

class Toyota : public Car
{
    public:
        Toyota();
        void method1();
};

class Lada : public Car
{
    public:
        Lada();
        void method1();
};

class User
{
    public:
        User();
        Car car;
};

int main()
{
    User user;
    Toyota toyota;
    user.car = toyota;
}
```

Comment: Make `car` data member a reference or a pointer.

Comment: You need to make `method1` `virtual`, and the `car` member should be a pointer/reference to `Car`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should use virtual functions inside car  and a reference pointer on assigning class toyota to car, the code i written below is working good.

```
#include <iostream>
using  std::cout;

 class Car
{
     public:
     Car(){cout << "A car";};
    virtual void method1(){cout << "from car";};    
 };

 class Toyota : public Car
  {
   public:
      Toyota(){cout << "A toyota";};
      void method1() {cout << "from toyota";};
  };

 class Lada : public Car
 {
     public:
       Lada(){cout << "A Lada";};
       void method1() {cout << "from lada";};
 };

  class User
  {
   public:
       User(){cout << "A user";};
       Car *car;
   };


  int main()
  {
     User *user = new User();
     Toyota toyota;
     user->car = &toyota;
      delete user;
    /***
      if you dont need pointers then
       User user;
       Toyota toyota;
       user.car = &toyota;
    /**
   }
```

Comment: Always remember: for every `new` there must be a `delete` somewhere. In a small thest program like this, the operating system will free the memory for you after your program completes, but you should accustom yourself to always `delete` dynamically allocated objects.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve this. One approach is to use pointers or references which allow you to use runtime polymorphism. A pointer or reference to a `Car` can also point to any object of a class derived from `Car`. However to get true polymorphism you need to declare the methods `virtual`. Also you really should delcare a `virtual ~Car() = default` destructor:

```
struct Car {
    virtual ~Car() = default;   // virtual destructor is important if you
                                // hold owning references or pointers that
                                // you want to use to destroy the object
                                // (like for example std::unique_ptr)
    
    virtual void method1();     // declare this virtual if you want
                                // polymorphic behaviour on method1
};

struct Toyota : public Car {
    void method1() override;    // no need to declare this virtual because
                                // it is already virtual in base class.
                                // the 'override' would warn you if there was
                                // no 'virtual method1' in the base class 
};

// ...

Toyota toyota;
Car& car_ref = toyota;
Car* car_ptr = &toyota;

car_ref.method1();              // calls Toyota::method1()
car_ptr->method1();             // calls Toyota::method1()
```

If using references or pointers you should keep in mind that they are non-owning. You **must** ensure, that the object that is referenced exists if you dereference the pointer or reference.

```
Car& f() {
    Toyota toyota;
    Car& car_ref = toyota;
    return car_ref;             // badooomz: return of reference to toyota
                                // that is going to be destroyed at the end
                                // of scope. You do not want this
}
```

An easy way to couple ownership to a pointer is to use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Car> f() {
    auto toyota = std::make_unique<Toyota>();
    return std::move(toyota);
}
```

---

An entirely different way to achieve your goal is to use static polymorphism (or duck typing) through `std::variant`:

```
struct Car {
    void method1();             // no virtual functions needed
};

struct Toyota {                 // note: no inheritance here
    void method1();
};

// ...

Toyota toyota;

// store a toyota in the variant
std::variant<Car, Toyota /*,...*/> car = toyota;

// call Toyota::method1()
std::visit([](auto&& car_like){ car_like.method1(); }, car);
```

Note that there is no relationship at all between `Car` and `Toyota` in this example. You could store any object in the variant, for which `obj.method1()` is a valid function call. That is why this kind of static polymorphism is called *duck typing* - anything that looks like a duck is treated like a duck. Note that when using `std::variant` you store a copy of the object and not a reference in the variant. Thus it is safe to return the variant from a function even if the original object is destroyed when leaving the function scope.